# Rename Proceed To Checkout Button in Woo-commerce

Tags: woocommerce

How Can Rename Proceed To Checkout Button in Woo-commerce 
i Was Looking For

> Add Filter

Answer (score 3):

I thought it would be a filter, but it turns out that the checkout link is a "pluggable function" instead. Place the following in your theme's functions.php:

```
function woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout() {
        $checkout_url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();

        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $checkout_url; ?>" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward"><?php _e( 'Checkout is this way' ); ?></a>
        <?php
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

WC_Cart::get_checkout_url is deprecated since version 2.5 .Use wc_get_checkout_url instead. So latest code will be

```
function woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout() {
        $checkout_url = WC()->cart->get_checkout_url();

        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $checkout_url; ?>" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward"><?php _e( 'Checkout is this way' ); ?></a>
        <?php
    }
```